# USB key input/output error

Tags: linux, ubuntu, usb

I'm having a problem with my USB key named "sdb", i get an input/output error when i try to use it.
I would like to make this usb key usable again.

> lsblk -S

```
    NAME HCTL       TYPE VENDOR   MODEL             REV TRAN
    sda  0:0:0:0    disk VendorCo ProductCode      2.00 usb
    sdb  1:0:0:0    disk SMI      USB DISK         1100 usb
```

sda is a working usb key.

When i try to mount /dev/sdb i get this error:

```
Can't read superblock on /dev/sdb
```

Heres some commands output which could help us:

> fsck /dev/sdb

```
fsck from util-linux 2.31.1
e2fsck 1.44.1 (24-Mar-2018)
fsck.ext2: Input/output error while trying to open /dev/sdb

The superblock could not be read or does not describe a valid ext2/ext3/ext4
filesystem.  If the device is valid and it really contains an ext2/ext3/ext4
filesystem (and not swap or ufs or something else), then the superblock
is corrupt, and you might try running e2fsck with an alternate superblock:
    e2fsck -b 8193 <device>
 or
    e2fsck -b 32768 <device>
```

The e2fsck commands show the same output.

then:

> fdisk -l /dev/sdb

```
fdisk: cannot open /dev/sdb: Input/output error
```

then:

> fdisk -l /dev/sdb0

```
Disk /dev/sdb0: 3,8 GiB, 4027580416 bytes, 7866368 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x0009bc1d

Device      Boot Start     End Sectors  Size Id Type
/dev/sdb0p1 *     2048 7866367 7864320  3,8G  c W95 FAT32 (LBA)
```

Comment: What is the question then? Few guesses: "why?", "how to make the device usable?", "how to recover data from the device?". Note these are not equivalent.. Please [edit] the post and specify your question. Additionally: what is the output of `ls -l /dev/sdb*`? anything interesting in `dmesg` just after you connect the device? It may simply be dead beyond repair.

Comment: My vote in on the "dead beyond repair", I'm sorry to say.

Comment: Did you try your device in any different system, like a Windows PC, or another Linux PC? Did you try any recovery software, a RUFUS at least?